# Set values with session.php does not work in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

The following code is in my session.php file:

```
class CI_Session {

    var $sess_encrypt_cookie        = FALSE;
    var $sess_use_database          = FALSE;
    var $sess_table_name            = '';
    var $sess_expiration            = 1000000;
    var $sess_expire_on_close       = FALSE;
    var $sess_match_ip              = FALSE;
    var $sess_match_useragent       = TRUE;
    var $sess_cookie_name           = 'ci_session';
    var $cookie_prefix              = '';
    var $cookie_path                = '';
    var $cookie_domain              = '';
    var $cookie_secure              = FALSE;
    var $sess_time_to_update        = 300;
    var $encryption_key             = '';
    var $flashdata_key              = 'flash';
    var $time_reference             = 'time';
    var $gc_probability             = 5;
    var $userdata                   = array();
    var $CI;
    var $now;
```

The issue: Although the var `$sess_expiration= 1000000;` which approx is more than 11 days, the session on my website (for a logged in user) seems to logout after somewhere close to 3 hours. What am I doing wrong? I tried many options but it does not work.

Comment: Why you doing that? you can set sessions in config.php?

Comment: @mustang83 yeah i have set it in my config.php now. Should i leave the 1000000 in session.php or should i change it ?

Comment: Because it's not safe to have it more for than 11 days recommend session to be logged out max 2-3 hours.

Comment: @mustang got ur point.....now should i leave the session.php file in the directory as it is or shoild i change the number to something else ?

Comment: Would recommend reading user guide more on sessions here is codeigniter 2.2.1 user guide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html and codeigniter 3 user guide http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the session expiration in the ./application/config/config.php file.

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
```

I would assume this is simply overriding yours.

It looks like you're editing the files within the system directory. **YOU SHOULDN'T.**

Comment: You are right @Craig
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200; is exactly the thing i have on my config.php file. Which is 2 hours. This is the issue. I have changed 7200 to 1000000 .
So now should i rewrite var $sess_expiration= 1000000; present in session.php file ?

Comment: I would leave the system files as they were. You should never have to edit them.